# Where to put rewrite rules in prestashop 1.7 .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Prestashop 1.7.2.4

After installation, the first lines of the generated .htaccess contains the following content:

```
# ~~start~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
# .htaccess automaticaly generated by PrestaShop e-commerce open-source solution
# http://www.prestashop.com - http://www.prestashop.com/forums

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> ... ..
```

When I install one of the modules, it adds its own rewrite rules at the end of the .htaccess.  This is done using PHP file functions (`file_put_contents`, `file_get_contents`) but with an append option. Unfortunately, this don't work until you put the rules on the top of the .htaccess file ( to precede some other rules that concern the same pattern). So I changed the behavior of module to prepend instead of appending.

The problem: I don't understand the comments  by PS at the beginning of .htaccess.  Does it mean module rules should necessarily be appended at the end(like module authors did)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of confusion we face since PrestaShop 1.5 whether a customized .htaccess file gets overwritten by PrestaShop during .htaccess generation or not.

In fact, PrestaShop will not overwrite changes in the `.htaccess` file if they custom rules are put in the correct places: **Before** **or after** the automatically generated rule mappings!

Example: .htaccess

```
Your custom rules

# ~~start~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again 
...
... auto-generated rules
...
# ~~end~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again

Your custom rules
```

PS: Changing core functionality sounds pretty bad.